# telethon TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python, telethon

My Code

```
#DATA
bot = "@bot"
ch1 = "t.me/bot"

async def work(client):
    async with client:
        me = await client.get_me()
        username = me.username
        print('Working with',username)
        print('')
        channel1 = await client.get_entity(ch1)
        await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel1))
        print(username, 'Some Text', ch1)
        print('----------------------------------------------------------')
async def main():
    asyncio.gather(
        await work(TelegramClient('user01', api_id, api_hash)),
    )
asyncio.run(main())
```

how to fix TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required ?